# D3.js check to see if a node has a class

Tags: class, d3.js, selection

I'm trying to write a `click` function to select the next `g.slice` node, add a class of `.sliceActive` to it and remove `.sliceActive` from the original `.slice`. However, only when you are at the last `g.slice` (with a class of `.slice5`) you would add the `.sliceActive` to the the first `g.slice` with a class of `.slice0`.

This is what I have so far that is not working. I think the problem is I don't know how to see if the current `.sliceActive` node also has the class of `.slice5`.

```
        $(".next").click(function(){
            var nextSlice;
            if(d3.select("g.sliceActive").hasClass("slice5")){
                nextSlice= d3.select(".slice0");
            }else{
                nextSlice= d3.select("g.sliceActive + g");
            }               
            d3.select("g.sliceActive").classed("sliceActive",false);
            nextSlice.classed("sliceActive",true);
        });
```

And here is how it looks in the web inspector:
[image]

Answer (score 46):

d3's `classed` function with no second parameter will return whether the selected element has the passed class.

```
d3.select("g.sliceActive").classed("slice5")
```

Should tell you what you need to know.